# ModuleNotFoundError: : No module named 'main.apps.mainconfigdjango'; 'main.apps' is not a package

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

This error occurred when I tried to run

`python3 manage.py makemigrations`

I'm really not sure what happens but I went into **mysite/mysite/settings.py** and added

`main.apps.MainConfig`

to the Installed Apps list. I am a beginner to python and the django framework and i would appreciate feedback from more experienced Python and Django developers.

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` file in the `main/apps` directory?

Comment: Please include your INSTALLED_APPS list from settings.py. It's possible that you might have missed a comma `,` after the string 'main.apps.MainConfig'. This would make Python/Django confused, leading to it 'melting together' your app's string and the following one's. So maybe what you're seeing is the result of having something like `'main.apps.mainconfig' 'django.contrib.admin'` instead of `'main.apps.mainconfig', 'django.contrib.admin'` in your list. I've had very similar errors happen because of the same mistake before.

Comment: I believe i have made that mistake, I'll fix it and see if it works, thank you

Comment: Yes, it has worked perfectly, thank you for your help.

Comment: It has worked perfectly thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.py look for INSTALLED_APPS and check if you have the correct name for your mainconfig or if there's a comma missing, if so add a comma after listing.